# Value of optional type 'Float?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Float'

Tags: swift

In short I am trying to do numerical operations between float values but cannot seem to find any solution.

```
var scale0: Float = 1.0
var scale1: Float = 1.0
var scale2: Float = 1.0
var scale3: Float = 1.0


let splitValues = message.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
    // These values are coming in realtime and constantly changing
    // Optional ?? incase we cannot convert string to float

    let value0 = Float(splitValues[0]) ?? Float("0.0")
    let value1 = Float(splitValues[1]) ?? Float("0.0")
    let value2 = Float(splitValues[2]) ?? Float("0.0")
    let value3 = Float(splitValues[3]) ?? Float("0.0")
```

All I am simplying trying to do is

```
if (value0 > scale0) {
    scale0 = value0
}
```

I am either faced with a:
Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float?' and 'Float'

or (when I wrap the variables around Float(var) etc

Value of optional type 'Float?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Float'

Comment: You can't compare optional and non optional values

Comment: `Float("0.0")` returns optional. You should replace that with only `0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your `valueX` variables are *optionals* because `Float("0.0")` returns
an optional. The possibility to compare optional and non-optional values
directly was removed in Swift 3 because its semantics are unclear, and it could lead to surprising results (see [SE-0121 – Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)).

What you want is

```
let value0 = Float(splitValues[0]) ?? 0.0
// ...
```

so that the value is either the result of the conversion of `splitValues[0]` to a floating point value  (if that represents a valid number), or zero.

Note that you code will still crash if the `splitValues` array 
contains less than 4 elements. Also `characters` is deprecated, and
the conversion from `Substring` to `String` not needed:

```
let splitValues = message.split{$0 == " "}
if splitValues.count >= 4 {
    let value0 = Float(splitValues[0]) ?? 0.0
    // ...
}
```

You can also use

```
let values = message.split{$0 == " "}.map { Float($0) ?? 0 }
```

or

```
let values = message.split{$0 == " "}.compactMap(Float.init)
```

to convert the string to an array of floating point values directly.
The first version replaces invalid numbers by zero, and the second
version skips invalid numbers.

Comment: Thank you for this! Would I be able to avoid a crash if I did a check for 4 array elements. Ie:
if (splitValues.count >= 4)

Comment: @TehNewbie: Sure. And btw, `characters` is deprecated, it should be `let splitValues = message.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)`